# Twitter APIs and adding Jars to Build path

Tags: android, eclipse, jar, buildpath

I am trying to manually add a jar file to my project for the 1st time.
I have downloaded Twitter4j in order to use these APIs in my app.
I extracted twitter4j-core-2.2.6-sources.jar and twitter4j-core-2.2.6-javadoc.jar and copied them to my /libs folder. Refreshed the  folder in eclipse and added the 2 files to my build path.
In the 'referenced libraries' and 'android dependencies' folder I can see my 2 new jars.
But I now have the following issues:
a)the sources cannot be viewed(I'll understand if they cannot be viewed, I am a C++ programmer, do I have to rely on the documentation to find out about the API names in Java?)
b)In eclipse, the javasources cannot be seen either: When i click on an item i get: Problem opening an editor. Reason Problem opening editor for (Annotations.xml)Unable to open external editor null xxx (org.eclipse.ui.browser.editorsupport)
c)I added one of the example files to my project and it does not compile: 
import twitter4j.Status; ==> The import twitter4j.Status cannot be resolved

Any help much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Don't create lib folder..you should have libs folder and eclipse will automatically add everything inside it to the build path for you. You don't need to do anything else except putting your jars there.

Comment: Hummm, it is actually in the libs folder, sorry for the typo. It did not get added automatically.